# Getting color from pixel and returning color code (in hexadecimal)

Tags: java, android, colors, color-picker

I want to be able to get the color from an image pixel and to display the color "code" on the screen in hexadecimal.
This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView touchedXY, invertedXY, imgSize, colorRGB;
ImageView imgSource1;
Button b, bOpenFromGallery;
static final int CAMREQUEST = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    touchedXY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xy);
    invertedXY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.invertedxy);
    imgSize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.size);
    colorRGB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colorrgb);
    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    bOpenFromGallery = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_openFromGallery);
    imgSource1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.source1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMREQUEST);

        }

    });

}

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMREQUEST) {

            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            Bitmap newBitmap = BITMAP_RESIZER(bitmap, 1280, 768);


            imgSource1.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
            imgSource1.setOnTouchListener(imgSourceOnTouchListener);
        }
    }
}

OnTouchListener imgSourceOnTouchListener
        = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        float[] eventXY = new float[]{eventX, eventY};

        Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
        ((ImageView) view).getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

        invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY);
        int x = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[0]);
        int y = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[1]);

        touchedXY.setText(
                "touched position: "
                        + String.valueOf(eventX) + " / "
                        + String.valueOf(eventY));
        invertedXY.setText(
                "touched position: "
                        + String.valueOf(x) + " / "
                        + String.valueOf(y));


        Drawable imgDrawable = ((ImageView) view).getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imgDrawable).getBitmap();

        imgSize.setText(
                "drawable size: "
                        + String.valueOf(bitmap.getWidth()) + " / "
                        + String.valueOf(bitmap.getHeight()));

        //Limit x, y range within bitmap
        if (x < 0) {
            x = 0;
        } else if (x > (bitmap.getWidth() - 1)) {
            x = bitmap.getWidth() - 1;
        }

        if (y < 0) {
            y = 0;
        } else if (y > (bitmap.getHeight() - 1)) {
            y = bitmap.getHeight() - 1;
        }

        int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

        colorRGB.setText("touched color: " + Integer.toHexString(touchedRGB));
         colorRGB.setTextColor(touchedRGB);

        return true;
    }
};

public Bitmap BITMAP_RESIZER(Bitmap bitmap,int newWidth,int newHeight) {
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);

    float ratioX = newWidth / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
    float ratioY = newHeight / (float) bitmap.getHeight();
    float middleX = newWidth / 2.0f;
    float middleY = newHeight / 2.0f;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, middleX - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bitmap.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

    return scaledBitmap;

}

}
```

The problem with that is that it returns something like "ff930d14" for red, which isn't the correct value of red. I want it to display "ff0000", the correct value of red.

Comment: How can I make it display the code without transparency? (instead of "ff930d14", to display "930d14")

Answer (score 0):

First off, your "correct" red is wrong.  It would be FFFF0000, as the first 2 characters are the transparency.  Secondly, there is no one "correct" red.  Very rarely is pure red used as a color.  It usually isn't maximum red (FFXY0000 is red for any value of XY, just different amount of brightness).  For that matter, mixing in small amounts of other colors like you see there is very common.  About the only time you'd get a pure color value is in a specially made example bitmap.  Real images use a variety of colors, that's why we have 32 bit color.

Basically what you want is wrong.  Its returning the right thing-  the actual color being used.  If you want to turn that into a human description of that color, like "red" or "magenta", you're going to need to create a mapping function.

Comment: How can I make it display the code without transparency? (instead of "ff930d14", to display "930d14")

Comment: Mask it off.  Use color= color & 00FFFFFF;

Comment: I am kinda newbie, can you please tell me exactly how to do it based on my code right here?